# Why does Visual Studio Code gives me gcc.exe: error : No such file or directory?

Tags: c, gcc, visual-studio-code

I just started programming in VS code (earlier used to code in Dev C) and I encountered with a strange error. Let me explain what happens.
I create a new file with C extension.
Write my program.
Run it.
It works.
Then I save it.
Close VS Code.
Opens the program from the place where it's saved.
VS Code opens up and I try to run it, I come across this error.

```
PS C:\Users\Malay\AppData\Local\Temp> cd "e:\C Data base\" ; if ($?) { gcc day 8 hw3.c -o day 8 hw3 } ; if ($?) { .\day 8 hw3 }
gcc.exe: error: day: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: error: 8: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: error: hw3.c: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: error: 8: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: error: hw3: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

How to solve it?

Comment: That compilation command is all kinds of wrong. How did you generate that? If you have spaces in your filename you should remove them

Comment: Whenever I try to run a saved program in VS code. I encounter this error.

Comment: Thanks UnholySheep. Removing the spaces from the filename solved the problem.

Comment: You need to quote file names with spaces in them. This is a simple beginner FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the spaces from the filename.
That'll do the work.